# Longest path in a tree - Spoj

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, tree, dijkstra

IDK what is wrong with my algo. Giving WA

I am using Dijkstra to find the distance of all node from starting node and then printing the maximum distance.

Link: http://www.spoj.com/problems/PT07Z/

```
#define REP(i,n) for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
#define FOR(i,start,end) for(int i=start;i<end;i++)
#define pii pair< int, int >

struct comp {
    bool operator() (const pii &a, const pii &b) {
        return a.second > b.second;
    }
};
priority_queue< pii ,vector< pii >, comp > Q;
#define Size 10009
vector<pii > G[Size];
int D[Size],Visited[Size];
int main() {
    int n,m,s=1,t,a,b,p,q,d;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    REP(i, t-1) {
        scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
        G[a].push_back(pii(b, 1));
        G[b].push_back(pii(a, 1));
    }
    REP(i, t+2){D[i]=1000000;Visited[i]=0;}
    D[s]=0;
    Q.push(pii(s,0));
    while (!Q.empty()) {
        a=Q.top().first;
        Q.pop();
        if (Visited[a]) continue;
        m=G[a].size();
        REP(i, m){
            p=G[a][i].first;
            if (!Visited[p] && D[a]+1<D[p]) {
                D[p]=D[a]+1;
                Q.push(pii(p,D[p]));
            }
        }
        Visited[a]=1;
    }
    m=0;
    FOR(i, 1, t+1) if(D[i]>m && D[i]!=1000000) m=D[i];
    printf("%d\n",m);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to use dijsktra for this problem as the edges are not weighted.

This problem is related to : ["Find Tree Diameter"](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/22855/algorithm-to-find-diameter-of-a-tree-using-bfs-dfs-why-does-it-work) which you can easily solve:

- Start from a node A and run a BFS.
- now take the farthest node from A
  (lets Call it B) and run another BFS from their.
- then take the
  farthest node from B (lets Call it C). the longest distance in the
  tree is the distance between B and C.

Hope it helped.

Comment: I know this can be solved by BFS. I just wanted to know that what is wrong in this approach. Thanks.